# Best place to store user-friendly error messages and system error messages mapping in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, custom-error-handling

I am using soap, soap returns different error messages with numbers. Client want to map those to a list of more user friendly error messages.

So I am thinking create a mapping between those and always display the friendly error message.

However, where is the best place to store the mapping? Where it's easy to maintain and easy to setup(entering the mapping, it's a list of 100 messages).

I know asp.net has this resource file, not sure if this is a good way?

---

Comment: A resource file is fine, you can also think of storing them  a database table. Where do you store your asp.net content?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create an enumeration with all the error messages? Then check the error message returned with your enumeration and display the appropriate message.
Enumerations consists of a set of named constants and their values. The value can be your error code.

```
Public Enum ArrivalStatus As Integer
   Late = -1
   OnTime = 0
   Early = 1
End Enum
```

Example above is from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx

Here is the C# version :

```
public enum ArrivalStatus { Late=-1, OnTime=0, Early=1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of error message is less and it not going to change then go with Enumeration.
Else go with resource file, because it will be easy to handle and less complex for feature reference.